# UPDATE depending on SELECT results[MySQL]

Tags: mysql

I have been doubting the way I am currently converting ini commands to from SQL where I only want to update something if the account/row exists(or if a field matches/doesn't match a specific value).

The way I am currently doing it is:

1. Calling a SELECT query

   2. Grabbing the results from the SELECT query
   3. Calling an UPDATE query based on the conditions from the SELECT query.

Is there a way I can do this without making two callbacks?(The plugin that I am working off of utilizes callbacks since it's threaded).

Comment: Sorry, but your question is vague and unclear. Could you maybe give us an example helping to understand your flow of thoughts?

Comment: What I am currently doing :http://i.imgur.com/xUl0rpy.png As you can see I am sending different things so I can't really use cache_affected_rows(this returns false/true depending on if the update was successful) depending on different values. I do not believe this is efficent and I am wondering if there is another approach to doing this. This is written in PAWN utilizing a MySQL plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them together:

```html
UPDATE x WHERE 
  y = (
        SELECT z WHERE n
      )
```

Just replace the variables for your own SQL!

Hope this helps:)

Comment: I think you may've misunderstood me. I already have a y, but I do not want to do something if a result within z is more than an integer outside of the query.